# excel 2013 template image

Tags: excel, excel-2013, excel-template

I was wondering if anyone knew how to add an image to an excel template so that the image shows up in the create new file template area instead of just lines.

I've looked through all the settings and options I can think of but can't find any way to add an image so it looks like the pre-installed templates, any help would be appreciated.

Cheers!

Chris

Answer (score 0):

Been wracking my brain over the same issue.
The solution seems to quite simple (Excel 2010, but I guess Excel 2013 is the same in this respect).

When you insert an image, in the lower right corner of the image selection window, it shows "Insert". This is actually a menu. If you open it up, you can also select "Link to file" or "Insert and link" (translated from Dutch, so could be slightly different in English version :).

Now, the insert always leads to an image place holder, the other two actually result in an image being shown when you insert the file from templates.

Hope this works for you as well!